# (Oracle SQL) How do I update a table with a unique key after an insert?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE STATO_VERS_METODO(
    METODO INT NOT NULL,
    PROGETTO INT NOT NULL,
    VERS NUMBER NOT NULL,
    STATO VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT 'Nuovo' NOT NULL,
    NOTA_VERSM VARCHAR2(500),
    CONSTRAINT UK_STATO_METODO UNIQUE(METODO, PROGETTO, VERS)
);
```

If I insert a row with the same unique key (metodo, progetto, vers) I get an error for the violation of uniqueness. At this point I want to modify the row already present and update the "Notes" field, adding the value of :NEW.NOTE to the existing one.
I wrote this trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER AGGIORNA_NOTA_METODO
BEFORE INSERT ON STATO_VERS_METODO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    n_righe INT;
    nota VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n_righe FROM STATO_VERS_METODO WHERE METODO = :NEW.METODO AND PROGETTO = :NEW.PROGETTO AND VERS = :NEW.VERS;
    IF(n_righe > 0)
    THEN
        IF(:NEW.STATO = 'Modificato')
        THEN
            SELECT NOTA_VERSM INTO nota FROM STATO_VERS_METODO WHERE METODO = :NEW.METODO AND PROGETTO = :NEW.PROGETTO AND VERS = :NEW.VERS;
            UPDATE STATO_VERS_METODO
            SET NOTA_VERSM = nota||CHR(10)||:NEW.NOTA_VERSM WHERE METODO = :NEW.METODO AND PROGETTO = :NEW.PROGETTO AND VERS = :NEW.VERS;
        END IF;
    END IF;



END;
```

It gives me the error for the violation of uniqueness and does not update. 
How can I modify the existing row?

Comment: A before trigger doesn't stop the insert. So after this trigger is fired, the insert is still attempted. That's why you still get the error.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the exact errors you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: You just said: `If I insert a row with the same unique key (method, project, vers)....`. Maybe you want to set the `STATO` as 'Modificato' when you update a row?

Comment: @dmak2709 let me explain you with an example: 
let's say we have the following row in the table stato_vers_metodo (1, 1, 10, 'Modificato', 'Source code changed'). I insert a new row in stato_vers_metodo (1, 1, 10, 'Modificato', 'Minor fix') and this causes a violation of the unique constraint on the key (metodo, progetto, vers). So I can't insert the row but I want to modify the existing one by concatenating the NOTA_VERSM field to the old one like this: (1, 1, 10, 'Modificato', 'Source code changed Minor fix')

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use trigger. You need a Merge statement instead -

```
MERGE INTO STATO_VERS_METODO SVM
USING (SELECT 'new_metodo' METODO, 'new_progetto' PROGETTO, 'new_vers' VERS FROM DUAL) D
ON (SVM.METODO = D.METODO)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET NOTA_VERSM = NOTA_VERSM || CHR(10) || D.NOTA_VERSM
                         WHERE SVM.METODO = D.METODO
                              ,SVM.PROGETTO = D.PROGETTO
                              ,SVM.VERS = D.VERS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (METODO,
                              PROGETTO,
                              VERS,
                              NOTA_VERSM)
                      VALUES ('new_metodo',
                              'new_progetto',
                              'new_vers',
                              'new_versm');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I'm not familiar with merge, where should I enter this command? After the insert command or instead of it?

Comment: instead of it. If it found a record it does an update else insert.

Answer (score 0):

As Ankit pointed you don't need to use a trigger, but in case you are a beginner I will post an answer with a trigger.

After creating the table lets insert the first row with the following statement.

```
INSERT INTO STATO_VERS_METODO(METODO, VERS, PROGETTO, NOTA_VERSM) 
       VALUES (1, 1, 10, 'Source code changed')
```

Now our table has one row and look as follow:

```
METODO | VERS | PROGETTO |   STATO  |  NOTA_VERSM
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  10  |    1     |   Nuovo  |  Source code changed
```

Now since you declare you table with a constraint you can't insert another row with the same (METODO, PROGETTO, VERS) so something like:

```
INSERT INTO STATO_VERS_METODO(METODO, VERS, PROGETTO, NOTA_VERSM) 
       VALUES (1, 1, 10, 'New String')
```

Will throw an exception.

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (****.UK_STATO_METODO) violated ORA-06512
```

So if you want to change the value you need to do an `UPDATE`. But as you said in the comment section you need to concatenate the old and the new string. One solution could be to implement a trigger as follows.

```
create or replace TRIGGER AGGIORNA_NOTA_METODO
BEFORE UPDATE ON STATO_VERS_METODO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.STATO := 'Modificato';
    :NEW.NOTA_VERSM := :OLD.NOTA_VERSM || ' ' || :NEW.NOTA_VERSM; 
END;
```

Update the row:

```
UPDATE STATO_VERS_METODO SET NOTA_VERSM = 'Minor fix' 
       WHERE METODO = 1 AND PROGETTO = 10 AND VERS = 1;
```

Finally our table looks like this:

```
METODO | VERS | PROGETTO |      STATO    |         NOTA_VERSM
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  10  |    1     |   Modificato  |  Source code changed Minor fix
```

Also your trigger as you wrote it generates mutating table exception, [learn more](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/mutating-table-error-in-oracle/).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative with a trigger. 
So to update automatically when I insert the line and get the exception for the unique key, should I use merge as recommended by Ankit?

Comment: You don't update automatically on INSERT,only when an UPDATE statement occurs. Because the row with STATO 'Nuovo' doesn't exist yet. Please read the answer and check all the code.

Comment: I read the answer and thank you, I was just asking to find out if there was a way to "automatically" update the table instead of getting the uniqueness violation error

Comment: @Gibser, The best possible alternative is to use MERGE command. 1. You can avoid having a new object in your DB. 2. Triggers are not appreciated at all in RDBMS. Since you once executed them and forgot to maintain later.